# How to find maximum value and location of each slice of 3D array in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, max

What is the fastest way of calculating the maximum value, with it's corresponding index, of each 'slice' of a 3D array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say you have `A` with `n` slices (here I just made each slice 10 by 10, but this can be changed to any size):

```
A = rand(10,10,n);
```

You can reshape it to n-columns matrix, then take the maximum of each column:

```
[val,ind] = max(reshape(A,[],n),[],1);
```

The first output `val` will be an n-element vector with all the maximum values, and the second output `ind` will be their row index in the reshaped `A`.

Then you get the size of the slices:

```
sz = size(A);
```

and use it to find the row (`r`) and column (`c`) of each maximum element in each slice:

```
[r,c] = ind2sub(sz(1:2),ind)
```

So in this example (using `rand` and 10x10x6 array for `A`) you would get something like this at the end (but with different values):

```
val =
      0.99861      0.98895      0.98681      0.99991      0.96057      0.99176
r =
     9     7     3     8     2     9
c =
     1     1     8    10    10     5
```

Comment: Great solution - both the maximum value and index recovered without using for loops. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a matrix A with `n` layers, you can apply `max` function in two steps to get a 1 x 1 x n matrix with max of each layer

```
A = rand(10,10,n);
layer_max = max(max(A,[],1),[],2); % 1 x 1 x n matrix, use squeeze to remove extra dims 
layer_max = squeeze(layer_max);
```